# IndexError: index out of bounds, what I am doing wrong here?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am getting error IndexError: index out of bounds

My code is

```
for i in range(len(x_particle_position)):
    x_particle_position[i] += delta_translation_hat[i] * (np.cos(particle_heading_list[i] + delta_rotation_1_hat[i]))
    print("X is" , x_particle_position[i])
```

knowing that :

> x particle position length is = 5000
>
> particle heading list length is = 5000
>
> delta_translation_hat length is = 1000
>
> delta_rotation_hat length is = 1000

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Please provide sufficient detail for someone not looking at your screen to be able to answer this. Better yet, attempt to reproduce the error in a toy example and debug it yourself.

Comment: your i goes up to 5000, yet you use it to index an array of length 1000.

Comment: @MadPhysicist , I am not sure what more details is needed ? Thanks:)

Comment: @dm2 Thanks for clarifying, I think logically there is no way then to avoid such error but is there some trick to skip it from appearing?

Comment: Stack trace would be a good start. This appears to be a simple debugging issue. Have you run this in a debugger and checked the sizes vs indices at the step that crashes? That's part of your job before posting.

Comment: I am using linux terminal as a compiler and Atom as a " writing " tool. So not a debugger friendly ENV for my tasks. I think I know now the answer for my question from @dm2 anyways.

Comment: It's impossible to reproduce the problem using just the code in the question.

Comment: Why are you trying to do math on arrays/lists with different sizes (5000 and 1000)?  Do you understand the error?  Do those sizes make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess 2 issues:
you are iterating through (x_particle_position), but instead of starting from 0 and ending at (len(x_particle_position)-1), you go over the range
+
as mentioned, you are iterating though 5000 items (of x_particle_position), but delta_translation_hat has only 1000 items? (so this fails sooner then above mentioned issue)

Comment: The 5000 and 1000 difference is important.  But you got the `range` bit wrong.  `range(len(x))` is the correct usage when iterating over `x`.  The 0 is not needed, the `-1` adjustment is wrong.